# Custom TF-Keras Layer performs worse than built-in layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a CNN network using Tensorflow and the TF-keras API using a custom layer. This custom layer performs a 2D convolution with additional masking information but gave me a less than desirable result (~50% accuracy with 150 epochs).

To test my layer I stripped it down to perform a normal 2D convolution and also implemented a similar network using the built in keras.layers.Conv2D. with my custom layer, I still only achieve ~50% accuracy, but with the built in function I achieve ~97%. To Test it further, I created an custom layer, which only propagates values to the build in Conv2D layer, but it still performs only at around 50% accuracy.

Model with build-in layers:

```
image_input = Input(shape=(32,32,3,),dtype='float32',
    name='Image_Input')
mask_input = Input(shape=(32,32,),dtype='int32',name='Mask_Input')
weight_decay = 1e-4
conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3,),padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(image_input)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3,),padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(bn1)
bn2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
ml1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(bn2)
do1 = Dropout(0.2)(ml1)

conv3 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,),padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(do1)
bn3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,),padding='same'
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(bn3)
bn4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
mp2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(bn4)
do2 = Dropout(0.3)(mp2)

conv5 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3,),padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(do2)
bn5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
conv6 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3,),padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(bn5)
bn6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
mp3 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(bn6)
do3 = Dropout(0.4)(mp3)

flat = Flatten()(do3)
output = Dense(10,activation='softmax')(flat)

model = Model(inputs=[image_input,mask_input],outputs=[output])
```

Model with custom layer:

```
image_input = Input(shape=(32,32,3,),dtype='float32',
    name='Image_Input')
mask_input = Input(shape=(32,32,), dtype='int32',name='Mask_Input')
weight_decay = 1e-4

ml1 = ML2(32,
    (3,3,),
    padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(image_input)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(ml1)
ml2 = ML2(32,(3,3,),
    padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(bn1)
bn2 = BatchNormalization()(ml2)
mp1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(bn2)
do1 = Dropout(0.2)(mp1)

ml3 = ML2(64,(3,3,),
    padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(do1)
bn3 = BatchNormalization()(ml3)
ml4 = ML2(64,(3,3,),
    padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(bn3)
bn4 = BatchNormalization()(ml4)

mp2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(bn4)
do2 = Dropout(0.3)(mp2)

ml5 = ML2(128,(3,3,),
    padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(do2)
bn5 = BatchNormalization()(ml5)   
ml6 = ML2(128,(3,3,),
    padding='same',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
    activation='elu')(bn5)
bn6 = BatchNormalization()(ml6)
mp3 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(bn6)
do3 = Dropout(0.4)(mp3)

flat = Flatten()(do3)
output = Dense(10, activation='relu')(flat)
model = Model(inputs=[image_input,mask_input], outputs=[output])
```

Custom Layer:

```
class ML2(Conv2D):
    def __init__(self,
        filters,
        kernel_size,
        strides=1,
        padding='valid',
        data_format=None,
        activation=None,
        dilation_rate=1,
        use_bias=True,
        kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
        bias_initializer='zeros',
        kernel_regularizer=None,
        bias_regularizer=None,
        activity_regularizer=None,
        kernel_constraint=None,
        bias_constraint=None,
        trainable=True,
        name=None,
        **kwargs):

        super(ML2,self).__init__(
            filters,
            kernel_size,
            strides=strides,
            padding=padding,
            data_format=data_format,
            activation=activation,
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
            bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
            trainable=trainable,
            name=name,
            **kwargs)
```

In my understanding, both models should do the same. Even with slight errors due to randomness, the accuracy of both models should be comparable, but with the built in layer, it achieves nearly double the accuracy. This discrepancy is consistent through multiple runs and different implementations of the custom layer.

Checking my custom layer setup with the online resources, I didn't manage to find an implementation error, or anything saying, that custom layers performs worse than built in ones.

I'm at a loss here, and happy for every idea.
Thanks

Comment: What's your TF version?

Comment: I tried with the current stable (r.1.12), the current nightly (r.1.13) and the 2.0 preview. All with the same results, wich lead me to the conclusion, that I managed to do something stupid. I would like to know what.

Comment: could that be due to the rank variation?