# TF Keras Custom Layer accuracy drop with element-wise operations

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a custom layer for a TF Keras application. This layer should be able to perform a 2D convolution with additional masking information.

The layer is quite simple (omitting the init and compute_output_shape functions):

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    ks = self.kernel_size + (int(input_shape[0][-1]),self.filters)
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel',shape = ks)
    self.ones = self.add_weight(name='ones',shape=ks,
        trainable=False, initializer= initializers.get('ones'))
    self.bias = self.add_weight(name='bias',shape=(self.filters,))

def call(self,x):
    img,msk = x
    #img = tf.multiply(img,msk)
    img = tf.nn.convolution(img,self.kernel)
    msk = tf.nn.convolution(msk,self.ones)
    #img = tf.divide(img,msk)
    img = bias_add(img,self.bias)
    return [img,msk]
```

The problem lies within those two commented out lines. They should just provide a simple, element-wise multiplication and division. If they are commented out, everything works fine. If I just comment one in, the accuracy of my model drops by around factor 2-3.

For testing, I simply used a mask of ones. That should have no influence for the output of this layer or it's performance (in accuracy terms).

I tried this with the current version of TF (r 1.12), the current nightly (r 1.13) and the 2.0 preview. Also I tried to replace the troublesome lines with e.g. keras Lambda layers and keras Multiply layers.

This might or might not be correlated to this problem:
[Custom TF-Keras Layer performs worse than built-in layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692266/custom-tf-keras-layer-performs-worse-than-built-in-layer)

Mathematically the element-wise operations shouldn't have an impact (as long as the mask is only consistent of ones).

Also the element-wise operations shouldn't have an impact on the performance of this layer, since they don't influence the weights, and don't influence the data.

I don't know why this happens and hope some of you have an idea.

EDIT: Added kernel initializer, which I forgot before

Comment: are masks trainable?

Comment: No, they are given as part of the input. The convolution operation with the ones kernel is used to ensure, that the mask tensor has the same shape as the image. Thus the ones weight isn't trainable either.

Comment: @Leo Lee: If you want to add your comment as an answer, I will accept it. You pointed me in the right direction. Thank you very much for that.